# Getting 2nd level of JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have JSON data which follows this model:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionKey": 0,
      "question": "string",
      "required": true,
      "type": "multipleChoice",
      "maxSize": 0,
      "answers": [
        {
          "answer": "string",
          "answerKey": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": "string",
      "answers": [
        "string"
      ],
      "required": true,
      "maxSize": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I am having difficult getting all the fields > field values. When i do a var_dump($jsondata) it is printing all the data so I know I am getting and storing the data ok. I know I need to do a foreach statement like:

```
foreach ($jsondata as $data) { 
echo $data['fields'];
}
```

I know this is wrong but I don't know how to cycle through all the fields > field values. Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//Decode JSON string into a PHP array.
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

//Loop through it like any associative array.
foreach($jsonData['fields'] as $field){
    var_dump($field);
    echo $field['field'] , '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much Wayne, this works a treat. I tried doing a foreach inside a foreach as well and that wasn't the way to do it. What you did makes total sense. Cheers,